# React: run code only when the component is unmounted, but have access to updated state values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is a frequently asked question on react, but still not able to find a suitable solution. The thing I always found strange with react is that it does NOT provide a `useMount` and a `useUnmount` hooks. For the `useMount` equivalent, you can just add an empty dependency array  to a useEffect with /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */ to prevent the linter from complaining, or to just add the dependencies if you are sure they are not gonna change in the lifecycle of the component, and there you are, you run code only once, during the first render (while of course having dependencies because thats the challenge here). Well, the unmount is more strange. So Image this scenario: I a have a parent component that the only thing it does is to show and hide a childe component.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setShowChild(!showChild);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggle} variant="contained">
        Toggle
      </Button>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />

      {showChild ? <Child /> : "hidden"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I have a child component that has an array to its local state and has a button that pushes items to array. What I am trying to achieve is to have a useffect that runs **ONLY ONCE** and has a cleanup function, meaning that the only time this function will run will be when the component is unmounted. Indeed that's the case but when I am trying to access my array there it contains only the initial state. Obiously if I add my local state array in the dependency array of the useEffect, it will have the access I want **BUT** the cleanup function will run every time the array changes and not on the unmount.

```
const Child = () => {
  const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([]);

  const pushItem = () => {
    setTestArray((arr) => [...arr, { name: "just a name" }]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      //want to have access to testArray BUT ONLY on unmount
      console.log(testArray);
    };
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      //here obviously I have access but the cleanup function runs every time an item is pushed, which I don't want.
      console.log(testArray);
    };
  }, [testArray]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={pushItem} variant="contained">
        Push Item
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

So, the question is: how to run a function when the component is unmounted but at the same time access the most updated value of a piece of state. In this case access testArray on unmount and not on every change.

Comment: What problem are you tring to solve? I don't see the proper question here.

Comment: Updated. access testArray only once, on component unmount.

Comment: What problem are you facing(other than accessing array)? What's your clean up function used for? Can you provide more context on what acctually are you trying to do?

Comment: Its not a business logic issue. The business logic depends on accessing the array. There is nothing special about the array. Could be a string, a number or whatever. What matters is that this array is a reactive piece of state. The question is: how to run code on unmount while having access to the component's state BUT not run it every time the state changes.

Comment: `useEffect` is described in detail from the docs, it's best to read these through: [useEffect api docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect) , [Lifecycle of Reactive Effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects), and [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Parent = () => {
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);
  const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([]);

  const pushItem = () => {
    setTestArray((arr) => [...arr, { name: "just a name" }]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(testArray);
  }, [testArray.length]);
  const toggle = () => {
    setShowChild(!showChild);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle} variant="contained">
        Toggle
      </button>

      <br />
      <br />
      <br />

      {showChild ? <Child pushItem={pushItem} /> : "hidden"}
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ pushItem }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={pushItem} variant="contained">
        Push Item
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Best of luck bro :)